# PyQt SystemTrayIcon won't show when i set the application to start after login

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt

I have this application that controls a deamon of mine. It basically checks if the deamon is already running, if so it gives the option to close, if not it gives the option to close, also it offers you a log of it, and everything is on a menu that opens from a QSystemTrayIcon. When I run it it works perfectly fine, but when I set it to run automatically after i log in it runs, but the trayicon doesn't show, you can even see the process with "ps aux". I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
    from subprocess import call
    from subprocess import Popen
    import os
    import time
```

class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("./mail_open_process.png"))

    global closeAction
    global openAction
    global startOnLaunch

    self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
    openAction = self.menu.addAction("Open")
    closeAction = self.menu.addAction("Close")
    logAction = self.menu.addAction("Log")
    startOnLaunch = self.menu.addAction("Start on Launch")
    startOnLaunch.setCheckable(True)
    exitAction = self.menu.addAction("Exit")
    self.setContextMenu(self.menu)


    self.connect(openAction,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.openDaemon)
    self.connect(closeAction,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.closeDaemon)
    self.connect(logAction,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.openLog)
    self.connect(exitAction,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.Exit)
    #self.connect(startOnLaunch,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.startLaunch)


    if os.path.exists("/dev/repa"):
        closeAction.setVisible(True)
        openAction.setVisible(False)
    else:
        closeAction.setVisible(False)
        openAction.setVisible(True)


def Exit(self):
    os.remove("/tmp/daemonMenu.pid")
    sys.exit()

def openDaemon(self):
    call(["gksu", os.path.expandvars("$HOME")+"/repad/apps/repad -f"])
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.path.exists("/dev/repa"):
        closeAction.setVisible(True)
        openAction.setVisible(False)


def closeDaemon(self):
    call(["gksu", os.path.expandvars("$HOME")+"/repad/apps/repad -c"])
    time.sleep(1)
    if not os.path.exists("/dev/repa"):
        closeAction.setVisible(False)
        openAction.setVisible(True)

def openLog(self):
    Popen(["gedit", "/dev/repad.log"])

#def startLaunch(self):
 #   Dir = "/etc/init.d/S99scriptDaemon" 
  #  if startOnLaunch.isChecked():
   #         call(["gksu","cp ./S99scriptDaemon /etc/rc5.d"])
    #if not startOnLaunch.isChecked():
     #       call (["gksu","rm /etc/rc5.d/S99scriptDaemon"])
```

def main():

```
pid = str(os.getpid())
pidDir = "/tmp/daemonMenu.pid"
if os.path.isfile(pidDir):
    pidFile = open(pidDir,"r")
    pidLine = pidFile.readline()
    call(["kill", "%s" %(pidLine)])
    os.remove(pidDir)
file(pidDir, 'w+').write(pid)
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
main()
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon()
trayIcon.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have an app that starts minimized in systray and it often doesn't show up on startup. In fact I can reproduce by removing the systray, starting the app, adding a new systray applet -> the systray icon of my app does not show up. This happens only if the app was started with no systray. If it starts with systray, I can remove the add a new systray applet and the app systray icon will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. I made script start.sh and at startup system starts this script. In script I added 10 second delay before starting application. This script seems like this:

```
sleep 10
./main.py
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It's something to do with pyqt and the script. I tried running other applictions I have, that also uses pyqt for the GUI, through the script and it also won't show the GUI, even thought the application is actually running.